# Can I have my Discord Bot send a DM to each member of the channel every Friday at 10 AM?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently creating a bot for my team. I would like to have the Discord Bot automate a DM to each member of the channel at the end of each week. I have been attempting the code on Replit using .j and also used a code I found from an old thread from a year ago.

Ideally, this is what the general flow would look like.

1. 10 AM on Friday, Bot sends every member of the channel a Check-In Prompt.
2. Users respond to the Bot.
3. Bot says thank you.
4. Bot sends users' responses to a designated Admin

Here is the code I have thus far, but I am running into some syntax errors as well as being stuck in general.

```
client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user, discord.User, *, message=None) 
    if (message == None)
        await ctx.send('You need to put a message')
    else
        await user.send(message)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send('DM Successfully Sent')
        await ctx.author.send('"' + message + '"' + ' sent to ' + str(user))
        print('"' + message + '"' + ' sent to ' + str(user))
```

Any thoughts? I appreciate any and all insights!

Comment: Is this python.js or javascript.py? :)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I'm pretty new to this. Im using Replit and making a Node.js with all my code within the index.js

Comment: This isn't JavaScript it wont run in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Currently you use discord.PY not discord.js....

```py
client.command()
async def dm(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    if message is None:
        await ctx.send('You need to put a message')
    else:
        await user.send(message)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send('DM Successfully Sent')
        await ctx.author.send(f'"{message}" sent to {user.name}')
        print(f'"{message}" sent to {user.name}')
```

This is correct version of code which you posted.

And what do you need? Send message to GUILD members or SOME CHANNEL viewers?

UPD: send some message to all member with some role using command:
`!send_DMs @role <message>`

```py
client.command(name='send_DMs')
async def send_msg_to_all_memebers_with_role(ctx: commands.Context, role: discord.Role, *, message=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if message is None:
        await ctx.send('You need to put a message after role mention')
    else:
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.send(message)
                await ctx.author.send(f'"{message}" sent to {member.name}')
                print(f'"{message}" sent to {member.name}')
    await ctx.send('All DMs was successfully sent')
```

Comment: oh wow thank you! Ill try this today!

In regards to what I need, I want to send a Check In message every Friday at 10 AM to ALL members of the Discord server that the bot is a part of (ideally I would be able to specify which Roles I can target).